# Select part of a string and change it in lowercase or uppercase python 3.x

Tags: string, python-3.x

I want to convert a string so that the pair positions will be in upper case characters and the impair positions will be in lower case characters.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
def foldingo(chaine):
    chaineuh=chaine[0::2].upper()
    chaine=chaineuh[1::2].lower()

    return chaine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code takes every other character in `chaine`, uppercases them, and assigns those characters to `chaineuh`.

Then it takes every other character in `chaineuh`, lowercases them, and assigns those characters to `chaine` again. In other words:

```
abcdefg -> ACEG -> cg
```

You'll notice it's not keeping the characters that you're not trying to target.

You could try building all the uppercases and lowercases separately, then iterate with `zip` to get them together.

```
def fold(s):
    uppers = s[0::2].upper()
    lowers = s[1::2].lower()
    return zip(uppers, lowers)
```

But this doesn't quit work either, since `zip` gives you tuples, not strings, and will drop the last character in odd-lengthed strings

```
abcdefg -> ACEG, bdf -> ('A', 'b'), ('C', 'd'), ('E', 'f')
```

We could fix that by using a couple calls to `str.join` and using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with a `fillvalue=''`, but it's kind of like using a wrench to hammer in a nail. It's not really the right tool for the job. For the record: it would look like:

```
''.join([''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.zip_longest(uppers, lowers, fillvalue='')])
```

yuck.

Let's instead just iterate over the string and uppercase every other letter. We can use an alternating boolean to track whether we're upper'ing or lower'ing this time around.

```
def fold(s):
    time_to_upper = True
    result = ""
    for ch in s:
        if time_to_upper:
            result += ch.upper()
        else:
            result += ch.lower()
        time_to_upper = not time_to_upper
    return result
```

You could also use enumerate and a modulo to keep track:

```
def fold(s):
    result = ""
    for i, ch in enumerate(s):
        ch = ch.lower() if i % 2 else ch.upper()
        result += ch
    return result
```

Or by using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), `str.join`, and list comprehensions, we can make this a lot shorter (possibly at the cost of readability!)

```
import itertools

def fold(s):
    return ''.join([op(ch) for op, ch in zip(itertools.cycle([str.upper, str.lower]), s)]
```

Comment: Since this answer got accepted and I looked at it again, I thought I'd show the [haskell solution](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/5749eef9524bdb3f84c7916c3cc2e698) too (since I'm on a haskell kick lately)